# Static Functions in C#, Concurrency Problems

Tags: c#, asp.net, concurrency, static-methods

I have many static functions in my application which are being called several times throughout my application. Through increase of number of users, these functions might be called several more times. I am just wondering if these function create any concurrency problems. Some static functions in my application even interact with Database. I made sure that mostly my static functions uses only local variables. Some of my static functions are as follows.
Please have a look and suggest if any changes required.

```
public static bool ISValidString(string CheckString)
{
    if (CheckString != null)
        CheckString = CheckString.Trim();
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(CheckString) || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(CheckString) || CheckString == "-" ||
        CheckString == "NA" || CheckString == "." || CheckString == "--Select--" || CheckString == "0" || CheckString == "0.00" || CheckString == "00")
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}

    public static DataTable ProcessMaster(string Condition, string Master)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = (((DataSet)HttpContext.Current.Application[Master]).Tables[0].Select(Condition).Length>0)
            ? ((DataSet)HttpContext.Current.Application[Master]).Tables[0].Select(Condition).CopyToDataTable()
            : ((DataSet)HttpContext.Current.Application[Master]).Tables[0].Clone();
        return dt;
    }


    private static void GetPayTypes()
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Application["PayTypeMaster"] = DBFactory.GetMasters(null, "GetPayTypes");
    }
    public static DataTable GetPayTypes(string Filter = null, bool ForceRefresh = false)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Application["PayTypeMaster"] == null || ForceRefresh == true)
            GetPayTypes();

        string Condition;
        if (Factory.ISValidString(Filter))
            Condition = "PayTypeID like '%" + Filter + "%' or PayTypeDesc like '%" + Filter + "%'";
        else
            Condition = Filter;
        return Factory.ProcessMaster(Condition, "PayTypeMaster");
    }

    public static DataSet GetMasters(string Filter, string MasterName)
    {
        CompanyParams myparam = new CompanyParams();
        try
        {
            myparam.AddParameter("@TranType", MasterName);
            myparam.AddParameter("@Filter", Filter);
            return CompanyDB.GetData(SPNameMasters, myparam.Params);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: You are correct, these methods do not seem to be thread safe

Comment: If you use local variables you will be 100% safe. If you use shared data (such as `HttpContext.Current.Application[Master]`) then you will only be safe if that data is designed to be thread-safe. For example, I doubt that `GetMasters` is thread-safe.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using `HttpContext.Current.Application` rather than just declaring `static` (i.e. global) variables?

Comment: Both are same right, I want to load all my master tables only once for all the users, basically to reduce no.of interactions with database.

Comment: `Both are same right` - well, one is much easier to read and debug. Plus variables are strongly typed. Refactoring is easier. You can use things like `Lazy` rather than your null checking. etc etc.

Comment: HttpContext.Current.Application survives even when there are no active requestes, is it same with a class with Static Variables, when all the requests to the application cease to exist, do they still survive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why dont you use Monitor or simply lock statement around code where you are using application specific variables and dont want multiple threads to execute code at same time. Simplest way for mutual exclusion.

Answer (score 0):

As @ranjit powar suggested, I solved the problem using lock statement around code that uses application specific variables/static variables. Please find below the procedure. You need not do this when your function uses completely local variables.

```
            static Object LockMulti = new Object();

            lock (LockMulti)
            {
              -- Application specific variables/Static Variables Code Here
            }

            private static void GetPayTypes()
            {
                lock (LockMulti)
                {
                  HttpContext.Current.Application["PayTypeMaster"] = DBFactory.GetMasters(null, "GetPayTypes");
                }
            }
```

Also it would be best to use static variables insted of HttpContext.Current.Application variables. Both provide same functionality, but there are many advantages when you use Static variables like easy to debug, type safe, etc.,